# iis7 url rewrite for thousands of pages

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have inherited a site which has lots of searching on board and the previous developers use form GETS to do the searching, so there are thousands of poorly formed URLs that I need to rewrite and I am not sure of the best approach (or the how-to's).  I use url rewriting for friendly urls and the normal seo canonicalization etc, but never this kind of thing.  I know nothing about regex.

**Sample rewrites:**

```
/search_results.php/?resultpage=52&area=&minimumPrice=25000&maximumPrice=8000000&conversion=euros&orderby=price_desc
```

should go to `/search-results/`

```
/search_results.php/?resultpage=5&area=Central+Algarve
```

should go to `/area/central-algarve/`

I am not averse to sending all `.php` extensions with whatever query string to the home page because there are literally thousands.

Any help or advice gratefully received!